# @Where(clause = "DELETE_FLAG='N'") in base class not work

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Where(clause = "DELETE_FLAG='N'") //enable delete flag global  //TODO:????why not work!
public abstract class AuditedEntity extends BaseEntity {

    @CreatedBy
    private String createUserId;
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createTime;
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifyUserId;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModifyTime;

    private String deleteFlag;
} 
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "SYS_CATEGORY")
public class SysCategoryEntity extends AuditedEntity {
}
```

here is full code. when i add @Where(clause = "DELETE_FLAG='N'") on SysCategoryEntity , it's work.

Comment: Is this the full code example? Its an abstract class - what happens when you create a JPA Object backing to a table

Comment: @Where(clause = "deleteFlag='N'")

Comment: My column is DELETE_FLAG. @Where(sql)

Comment: your field is  private String deleteFlag; which maps to the column so @Where needs to point to the JPA name

Comment: no, still not work . and @where source write only "sql" suport,and for soft delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be a Hibernate Bug, see [HHH-8873](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8873)